# No number is added with reference items

Tags: bibtex, numbering, bibitem

I am using texmaker. the text of the `sample.bib` code is below,

```
@article{seqnn,
  author =       {Ilya Sutskever and Oriol Vinyals and Quoc },
  title =        {Sequence to sequence learning with neural networks},
  journal =      {Neural Information Processing Systems},
  year =         {2014}
}

@article{encdec,
  author =       {Kyunghyun Cho and Bart Van Merrienboer and Caglar Gulcehre and Dzmitry Bahdanau and Fethi Bougares and Holger Schwenk and Yoshua Bengio},
  title =        {Learning phrase representations using RNN encoder-decoder for statistical machine translation},
  journal =      {Conference on Empirical Methods in Natural Language Processing(EMNLP)},
  year =         {2014}
} 

@article{nmt,
  author =       {Dzmitry Bahdanau and Kyunghyun Cho and Yoshua Bengio},
  title =        {Neural machine translation by jointly learning to align and translate},
  journal =      {International Conference on Learning Representations},
  year =         {2015}
}
```

Now in the `*.tex` file I have added the following code at the end of the document to cite,

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrv} 
\bibliography{sample}
```

After compiling, the output is like below,

[image]

How can I add numbers at the left side of the each bibitem?

Comment: Change for example `\bibliographystyle{abbrv}` to `\bibliographystyle{plain}`.

Comment: still same. no number is added.

Comment: Clear all auxilliary files and start the compile chain again.

Comment: @Maruf Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

With the following MWE (package `filecontents` used to have TeX code and Bib file in one MWE):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@article{seqnn,
  author =  {Ilya Sutskever and Oriol Vinyals and Quoc },
  title =   {Sequence to sequence learning with neural networks},
  journal = {Neural Information Processing Systems},
  year =    {2014},
}
@article{encdec,
  author =  {Kyunghyun Cho and Bart Van Merrienboer and Caglar Gulcehre and Dzmitry Bahdanau and Fethi Bougares and Holger Schwenk and Yoshua Bengio},
  title =   {Learning phrase representations using RNN encoder-decoder for statistical machine translation},
  journal = {Conference on Empirical Methods in Natural Language Processing(EMNLP)},
  year =    {2014},
} 
@article{nmt,
  author =  {Dzmitry Bahdanau and Kyunghyun Cho and Yoshua Bengio},
  title =   {Neural machine translation by jointly learning to align and translate},
  journal = {International Conference on Learning Representations},
  year =    {2015},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{Goossens} and \cite{adams}.

\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys
\bibliographystyle{plain} % abbrv
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

commpiled with the usual commands

```
pdflatex mwe.tex
bibtex mwe
pdflatex mwe.tex
pdflatex mwe.tex
```

results in the following bibliography:

[image: resulting bibliography]